# What is this large houseplant with long oval leaves?

Tags: identification, houseplants

[image: houseplant]

This was gifted from work but no one here or at the local nursery can identify it.

Comment: well, it's not an oleander.  Is there any smell to the leaves when crushed?  What colour is the sap?  What colour is the stem and are the older stems a different colour?

Comment: Older stems are woody and resemble the stem of a "money tree". The newer stems are green, there is no sap and the scent is a fresh green smell.

Answer (score 2):

I have an avocado plant and this looks like it.

Comment: Please add some detail: what characteristics of the plant make you think it's an avocado.

Comment: avocado leaves are normally wider with more prominent veins.

Answer (score 2):

Could this be a garden croton? We have one at home that has narrow leaves attached to the woody stem in this way. It tends to stay dark green when grown in a shady area/does not get any full sun.

Answer (score 0):

It is an Ardisia elliptica. A highly invasive shrub/tree to the southern United States, but is kept also as an ornamental houseplant. I have the same houseplant and assumed it was a species of Ficus for many years until the plant bloomed. If your plant has produced small, white-pink flowers that are bundled together facing downwards, it is almost definitely an Ardisia elliptica.